# visualization of convolutional layer in keras model

Tags: python, visualization, keras

I created a model in Keras (I am a newbie) and somehow managed to train it nicely. It takes 300x300 images and try to classify them in two groups.

```
# size of image in pixel
img_rows, img_cols = 300, 300
# number of classes (here digits 1 to 10)
nb_classes = 2
# number of convolutional filters to use
nb_filters = 16
# size of pooling area for max pooling
nb_pool = 20
# convolution kernel size
nb_conv = 20

X = np.vstack([X_train, X_test]).reshape(-1, 1, img_rows, img_cols)
y = np_utils.to_categorical(np.concatenate([y_train, y_test]), nb_classes)

# build model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, nb_conv, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, nb_conv))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# run model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now I would like to visualize the second convolutional layer and if possible also the first dense layer. "Inspiration" was taken from [keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html). By using `model.summary()` I found out the name of the layers. Then I created the following frankenstein code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from scipy.misc import imsave
import numpy as np
import time
#from keras.applications import vgg16
import keras
from keras import backend as K

# dimensions of the generated pictures for each filter.
img_width = 300
img_height = 300

# the name of the layer we want to visualize
# (see model definition at keras/applications/vgg16.py)
layer_name = 'convolution2d_2'
#layer_name = 'dense_1'

# util function to convert a tensor into a valid image
def deprocess_image(x):
    # normalize tensor: center on 0., ensure std is 0.1
    x -= x.mean()
    x /= (x.std() + 1e-5)
    x *= 0.1

    # clip to [0, 1]
    x += 0.5
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 1)

    # convert to RGB array
    x *= 255
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        x = x.transpose((1, 2, 0))
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
    return x

# load model
loc_json = 'my_model_short_architecture.json'
loc_h5 = 'my_model_short_weights.h5'

with open(loc_json, 'r') as json_file:
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()

model = keras.models.model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

# load weights into new model
model.load_weights(loc_h5)
print('Model loaded.')

model.summary()

# this is the placeholder for the input images
input_img = model.input

# get the symbolic outputs of each "key" layer (we gave them unique names).
layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers[1:]])


def normalize(x):
    # utility function to normalize a tensor by its L2 norm
    return x / (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(x))) + 1e-5)


kept_filters = []
for filter_index in range(0, 200):
    # we only scan through the first 200 filters,
    # but there are actually 512 of them
    print('Processing filter %d' % filter_index)
    start_time = time.time()

    # we build a loss function that maximizes the activation
    # of the nth filter of the layer considered
    layer_output = layer_dict[layer_name].output
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, filter_index, :, :])
    else:
        loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])


    # we compute the gradient of the input picture wrt this loss
    grads = K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0]

    # normalization trick: we normalize the gradient
    grads = normalize(grads)

    # this function returns the loss and grads given the input picture
    iterate = K.function([input_img], [loss, grads])

    # step size for gradient ascent
    step = 1.

    # we start from a gray image with some random noise
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        input_img_data = np.random.random((1, 3, img_width, img_height))
    else:
        input_img_data = np.random.random((1, img_width, img_height, 3))
    input_img_data = (input_img_data - 0.5) * 20 + 128

    # we run gradient ascent for 20 steps
    for i in range(20):
        loss_value, grads_value = iterate([input_img_data])
        input_img_data += grads_value * step

        print('Current loss value:', loss_value)
        if loss_value <= 0.:
            # some filters get stuck to 0, we can skip them
            break

    # decode the resulting input image
    if loss_value > 0:
        img = deprocess_image(input_img_data[0])
        kept_filters.append((img, loss_value))
    end_time = time.time()
    print('Filter %d processed in %ds' % (filter_index, end_time - start_time))

# we will stich the best 64 filters on a 8 x 8 grid.
n = 8

# the filters that have the highest loss are assumed to be better-looking.
# we will only keep the top 64 filters.
kept_filters.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
kept_filters = kept_filters[:n * n]

# build a black picture with enough space for
# our 8 x 8 filters of size 128 x 128, with a 5px margin in between
margin = 5
width = n * img_width + (n - 1) * margin
height = n * img_height + (n - 1) * margin
stitched_filters = np.zeros((width, height, 3))

# fill the picture with our saved filters
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        img, loss = kept_filters[i * n + j]
        stitched_filters[(img_width + margin) * i: (img_width + margin) * i + img_width,
                         (img_height + margin) * j: (img_height + margin) * j + img_height, :] = img

# save the result to disk
imsave('stitched_filters_%dx%d.png' % (n, n), stitched_filters)
```

After executing it I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user/conv_filter_visualization.py in <module>()
     97     # we run gradient ascent for 20 steps
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    857         t0_fn = time.time()
    858         try:
--> 859             outputs = self.fn()
    860         except Exception:
    861             if hasattr(self.fn, 'position_of_error'):

ValueError: CorrMM images and kernel must have the same stack size

Apply node that caused the error: CorrMM{valid, (1, 1)}(convolution2d_input_1, Subtensor{::, ::, ::int64, ::int64}.0)
Toposort index: 8
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, 4D), TensorType(float32, 4D)]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 3, 300, 300), (16, 1, 20, 20)]
Inputs strides: [(1080000, 360000, 1200, 4), (1600, 1600, -80, -4)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Elemwise{add,no_inplace}(CorrMM{valid, (1, 1)}.0, Reshape{4}.0), Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (Abs(i1) + i2 + i3))}}[(0, 1)](TensorConstant{(1, 1, 1, 1) of 0.5}, Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, CorrMM{valid, (1, 1)}.0, Reshape{4}.0)]]

Backtrace when the node is created(use Theano flag traceback.limit=N to make it longer):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 787, in from_config
    model.add(layer)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 114, in add
    layer.create_input_layer(batch_input_shape, input_dtype)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 341, in create_input_layer
    self(x)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 485, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 543, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 148, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 356, in call
    filter_shape=self.W_shape)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 862, in conv2d
    filter_shape=filter_shape)
```

I guess I am having some bad dimensions, but don't even know where to start. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get the weights or the intermediate outputs?

Comment: @MikaelRousson: I would like to plot each "what sort of input maximizes each filter" in my second convolutional layer. As I understand it I created a real mess here :)

Answer (score 4):

Keras makes it quite easy to get layers' weights and outputs. Have a look at https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/ or https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#the-concept-of-layer-node.

You can basically get it with the properties `weights` and `output` of each layer.

Answer (score 3):

Just a simple function like

```
def plot_conv_weights(model, layer_name):
    W = model.get_layer(name=layer_name).get_weights()[0]
    if len(W.shape) == 4:
        W = np.squeeze(W)
        W = W.reshape((W.shape[0], W.shape[1], W.shape[2]*W.shape[3])) 
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(5,5, figsize=(8,8))
        fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .5, wspace=.001)
        axs = axs.ravel()
        for i in range(25):
            axs[i].imshow(W[:,:,i])
            axs[i].set_title(str(i))
```

can solve your problem (only convolutional layer)

Comment: Can this method be adapted for a Conv1D case? I tried it and it came up with an empty image.... I want to be able to see what is being done to the 1D vectors, that I'm studying, in the intermediate layers...

Comment: in  Conv1D, the kernel/weight of each layer is Rank1 or Rank0 tensor, so there is no point to plot it.i think....  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TensorRank.html

Comment: Is there a way to discover a general trend that is being recognised in the 1D convolution? I tried plotting the bias. For example if train a binary classifier and I plot the bias and see an oscillating line- does this mean that my data have a regular pattern- that might be distinguishing the rows with '1 labels' from '0s'? @Merdan Memtimin

Comment: A bias can be understood as the weights' distribution center of the corresponded layer. in the other words, assume your weights are followed the normal distribution, the the bias is more like a mean of them, so, yes, the bias is representing some pattern of your data, but not main part, because you can train your Deep Net without bias, but it will be low efficiency. And back to your question, if you are able to project your weights(each layers') in Gaussian, and if they show multi-variance then i think you are able to prove your point.i suggest you to ref. tf.summary.histogram @which_command

Comment: As addition, check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315202/understanding-tensorboard-weight-histograms       @which_command

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/9jp6jv/checking_if_convolutional_weights_are_normally/ @Merdan Memtimin could you take a look at the following link. I tried using your advice- thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your Network, there are only 16 filters in the first convolution layer and then 16 in the next, so you have 32 Convolution filters. But you are running the for loop for 200. Try to change it to 16 or 32. I am running this code with TF backend and it is working for my small CNN. 
Also,change the image stitching code:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if(i * n + j)<=len(kept_filters)-1:
```

Best of Luck...